# shell script to get the file name from a string

Tags: shell, ksh

I need to get the basnename of the file (esrt-deghasdf-keystore) before .jks. I want to do it using shellscript. Is it possible?

```
abcdefgh 7369 4825 0 00:12:26 pts/10 0:37 java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/abc3/esrt/der/fer-def2/esrt-deghasdf-keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the format of the line.  If you lines are all going to end in `/path/to/file.ext` format, you can do:

```
echo $line | sed -e 's@.*/@@g' -e 's@\.[^.]*$@@g'
```

but really, it depends upon how exactly your lines are formatted and what you want out of it.

Answer (score 2):

no need external tools. ksh can do the job

```
$ var="abcdefgh 7369 4825 0 00:12:26 pts/10 0:37 java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/abc3/esrt/der/fer-def2/esrt-deghasdf-keystore.jks"

$ echo ${var##*/}
esrt-deghasdf-keystore.jks

$ var=${var##*/}
$ echo ${var%.*}
```

Comment: Since the OP wanted the extension removed: `file=${var##*/}; base=${file%.*}`

Answer (score 1):

Use cut piped to sed. (some thing like cut -f 7 | sed blah)

Sorry I don't remember exactly how to use both.

See the manpages: [cut](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut) and [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)